# display featured image in RSS feed

Tags: rss, customization

Hay, does anyone know a way to display the featured image url within the RSS feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function add_featured_image_url($output) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        $output = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ) . ' ' . $output;
    }
    return $output;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'add_featured_image_url');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'add_featured_image_url');
```

Comment: I've added this to my templates functions.php file, but when i read the feed i cannot see it. Do i need to do anything else to it?

Comment: Oh, a follow up. I'm using php's SimpleXmlElement() and reading the file through that. Will that make a difference?

Comment: ... nope reply. any ideas?

Comment: I missed you previous comments. There was an error in my answer, I edited it.

Comment: Sorich I think there's still an error, the code above will remove the post content and replace it with the url instead of adding it. Needs to be $output .= wp_get_att[...] instead of =

Comment: No, this is not an error. $output is concatenated after wp_get_attachment_url. I tested it. Please read the code again.