# Getting Thumbnail in fetch_feed from custom field

Tags: rss, feed

i have setuped showing rss from my network site using fetch_feed();

```
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('rss link here');
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
THen i can use foreach to get these 
$item->get_description(); 
$item->get_permalink();
$item->get_title();
get_date('j F Y | g:i a');
```

But i am not sure how to get thumbnail in my feed or here in this system.
But in my posts i do have a custom field called post-img for displaying posts.

Help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the full code block?

Comment: this is pretty much the complete code.. just need echos in the last 4 lines..

Comment: Can you post a link to the feed you're parsing? It's likely that your custom field (`post-img`) isn't in the feed to begin with, but without knowing what the field is we can't help you parse it.

Comment: sure its, http://apps.designzzz.com/feed/ and yes it doesn't contain a thumbnail. i tried some functions from google whihc will add thumbnail to feed but instead it started showing the entire post in feed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Codex, [fetch_feed()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) uses the SimplePie engine for parsing RSS.

So, if `$item->get_title();` is working, then you should be able to do:

> `$item->get_thumbnail();`

as per the [SimplePie documentation](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_enclosure/get_thumbnail), as long as there are any thumbnails already on the feed.

**UPDATE:**

Before running the above, you have to insert the images on your feed. Check for [*display featured image in RSS feed*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/display-featured-image-in-rss-feed) and [*How to grab first image attached to post and display in RSS feed?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10447/how-to-grab-first-image-attached-to-post-and-display-in-rss-feed) topics on it.

Comment: i have already checked that but it dosen't work maybe because there is no thumbnail in the feed im fetching but yes i do have a custom field in that feed's posts which got link to thumbanil..

Comment: updated answer with links to "how to place custom field images on RSS"

Comment: k i have used the second method it worked and added first image in the feed, but now on getting the feed it gives thsi error :  Call to undefined method SimplePie_Item::get_thumbnail()

Comment: Did you try using the enclosure method described on the docs? -> http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_enclosure/get_thumbnail