# Can't Display Featured Image in RSS Feed

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, rss

I'm currently working on a test website on my local server using WordPress version 3.4.2. I've tried various different solutions. Some have included installing various plugins, such as WP RSS Images and Featured Image in RSS. Even tried some of the solutions from the following posts:

- [display featured image in RSS feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/display-featured-image-in-rss-feed)
- [How to grab first image attached to post and display in RSS feed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10447/how-to-grab-first-image-attached-to-post-and-display-in-rss-feed)
- [Add a Post Thumbnail to an RSS Feed with custom size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65617/add-a-post-thumbnail-to-an-rss-feed-with-custom-size)

Yet, it seems the images aren't being posted to the RSS feeds. Is there another solution that can solve this problem?

The RSS feed I'm trying to include images is [this link](http://readbuzz.com/feed).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This works out of the box in WordPress core, and the RSS feed you linked **does** include featured images. Where is the problem?

Comment: @ChipBennett That's weird because on my computer, the images aren't displaying in the RSS feeds.

Answer (score 1):

By default, RSS won't display. You have to use RSS2. However this will help you. Paste it in your functions.php:

```
function insert_thumbnail_into_feed() {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
    // replace thumbnail with yours
    $content = '<p>' .get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) .'</p>';
}

// get post content and replace feed content with
// you can also limit/filter the content to exclude shortcodes and HTML code etc.
$content .= '<p>' .get_the_content() .'</p>';

return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'insert_thumbnail_into_feed' );
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'insert_thumbnail_into_feed' );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where's the filter hook?

Answer (score 0):

Strange none of the links above doesn't work for you.

You can try this using Custom RSS Feed method very well explained by Joost ( For reference: http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/ ). Using this way, you can display any of the fields either custom field value or featured image.